# MDX different expressions, same result

Tags: ssas, mdx, cube

The following two statements return the same results in the cube, is one more optimized than the other or is there some compiler magic happening in the background?

```
CREATE MEMBER
    CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Total Interest Expense]
AS
    AGGREGATE(
        EXISTING({([GL Income Statement Account].[Account Type].&[INTEREST EXPENSE])}),
        [Measures].[Amount]
    )



CREATE MEMBER
    CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Total Interest Expense]
AS
    (
        [GL Income Statement Account].[Account Type].&[INTEREST EXPENSE],
        [Measures].[Amount]
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are actually pretty much the same expressions. **In the first expression**, the `Measures.[Amount]` is aggregated over the set `[GL Income Statement Account].[Account Type].&[INTEREST EXPENSE]`(which is actually a member). The `EXISTING` clause does not have any significance as you are making the set(first parameter to the `AGGREGATE` function) context independent by defining it as a member. **In the second expression**, the value of the measure is evaluated over the set(which) is again just a member. (Tuples comprising a measure are actually numeric in nature).